# jquery animate background to none

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a hover effect that animates the background of an element with no background, the animation works on hover, but then it will not go back to no background:

```
$('#home_sensors_products').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ 
        'background-color':'#fff',
        'color':'#3463a0'
    }, '2000');
    },function(){
    $(this).animate({ 
        'background-color':'none',
        'color':'#fff'
    }, '2000', 'linear');
});
```

How do I animate the background back to no background? I have tried background:none and transparent as well all with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like JQuery inherently supports animating to a non-numeric property value.  You can find that limitation mentioned [here in the JQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties).

The documentation does make mention of JQuery.Color, a plugin that helps alleviate this limitation.  Here's an idea of how you'd update your code using the plugin:

```
$('#home_sensors_products').hover(function(){  
    $(this).animate({ 
        'background-color':'#fff',
        'color':'#3463a0'
    }, '2000');
    },function(){
    $(this).animate({ 
        // rgba(255,255,255,0) is a transparent white.  Good for transitioning from #FFF
        'background-color':'jQuery.Color(rgba(255,255,255,0))',
        'color':'#fff'
    }, '2000', 'linear');
});
```

You can check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nev1hss9/) to see this in action.